# CakePHP 2.0 - Able to Register, but cannot login

Tags: cakephp

Im CakePHP newbie, apologies if the question has been asked i search it but could not find. I have problem with the code below. It works well when it i register new user, problem when im trying to login i get and error "Invalid username or password'); Please help

```
public function login() {

if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ((!empty($this->request->data['User']) && $this->Auth->login())) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome, '. $this->Auth->user('username')));
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password'));
        }
    } 
}
```

//*********** LOGIN CTP************

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>

<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Please enter your username and password'); ?></legend>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>
```

//*********************BEFORE SAVE ***************************

```
 public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    // hash our password
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }

    // if we get a new password, hash it
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password_update']) && !empty($this->data[$this->alias]['password_update'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password_update']);
    }

    // fallback to our parent
    return parent::beforeSave($options);
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but it's likely your username or password is wrong.  Did you follow the tutorial?  If so, pls provide the rest of the related code (ie beforeSave...etc)  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Comment: password and username are correct.

Comment: Are you encrypting your password? Is the password field length enough to store all the encrypted password?

Comment: thank Eagle.. its working my password field was 16 and change it to longer length.. Thankx a lot

Comment: It doesn't appear you followed the tutorial.  I would suggest doing that first, just to get it working, then branching out w/ any customizations.

Comment: I think this is the password can you to send the password to your model but is saved differently in your Data Base What are you doing in your appController? specifically in your beforeFilter()

Comment: Along the same lines as eagle: I had a similar problem, my issue was I set the DB password length to varchar (50), This is too short, when I set it to varchar (255) it worked due to the length of the hash. Hope this helps.